# sql syntax - opposite select

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have 2 tables: (These are not the real tables, I made it simple for the demo)

```
> 1. Students_Table - with ID column (and others)
> 2. Students_Pictures_Table : with ID column and PIC(Blob) column
```

> I need SQL syntax which will return only the students ID for those who
>   exists in Students_Table but don't exist in Students_Pictures_Table .

Comment: mysql AND db2? Please don't tag products not involved. What have you tried? And why didn't it work? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: Tip: `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

`not exists` and a correlated subquery is perhaps the simplest approach

```
select s.id
from students s
where not exists (select 1 from student_pictures p where p.id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` to get the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM Students s LEFT JOIN Students_Pictures sp ON s.id = sp.student_id
WHERE sp.id IS NULL
GROUP BY s.id;
```